# How to import a user defined class from a Package to a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to create a project with the following structure:

```
my_file.ipynb
my_package_directory > __init__.py test.py
```

Within `test.py` lets say I have a very simple class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

from with in a code cell I try to insatiate the class and print out the defined variable:

```
from my_package_directory.test import Test
test = Test('bob')
print(test.name)
```

If I try to run the cell I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Test' from 'my_package_directory.test'
```

Is there a certain way to do this in a Jupyter notebook?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you double-check your namings with e.g `import my_package_directory.test as t; print(dir(t))` ?

Comment: I think this outputs as expect `['Test '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'const', 'os']`

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct, so it's not about the import path. What's suspect is the `const` and `os` in that output list since those aren't imported or defined in that `test.py`...

Comment: They are in the actual file. I was just trying to simplify things. Commenting them out makes no difference.

Comment: Then I'd just check the spelling of everything. Maybe also restart the notebook kernel just in case...

Comment: thanks, I will review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the root of your files is not in the [python module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).
You can check your module search path with:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If you append the location of your notebook and your package to that path, it should be importable:

```py
sys.path.append('/path/to/where/jupyter/notebook/resides')
from my_package_directory.test import Test # should work
```

Note that you have to restart the kernel whenever you change the implementation of your module - This can be circumvented with some [jupyter notebook magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

Comment: That seems to solve the import problem but it then gives a `TypeError` saying the Test() takes no arguments. Does Jupyter have any kind of caching that would  cause this maybe? It's like it's not recognising changes to the class file. Even when I delete the cell and try again.

Comment: Actually restarting the kernel solved it. Many thanks

Comment: See the edit above ;-) Good luck!